# ASP.NET Core - unable to set and read a cookie

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-identity

As part of an authentication flow, I need to set a temporary cookie to store some user properties across a trip to an external identity provider. I may have misunderstood, but I thought I could use `SignInAsync` and `AuthenticateAsync` to store and retrieve user data from cookies inside controller actions:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FirstEndpoint()
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("TestClaim", "TestClaimValue"));
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties { Items = {{"TestProp", "TestPropKey" }}};

        // Issue Cookie for response
        await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync("MyTempCookieScheme", principal, props);

        // This will ultimately go elsewhere, but for example purposes just redirect to another action
        return RedirectToAction("Callback");
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
    {
        // Is this not how I would get a user / ClaimsPrincipal from the cookie?
        var result = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("MyTempCookieScheme");
        // SUCCEEDED IS FALSE :(
        if (result?.Succeeded != true)
        {
            throw new Exception("External authentication error");
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

In my `Startup` I have:

```
       services.AddAuthentication(options => { options.RequireAuthenticatedSignIn = false; })
            .AddCookie("MyTempCookieScheme")
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what your goal is, so perhaps you can help me understand? What kind of data do you need to be able to retrieve when you are in the Callback() method?

Comment: Sure. See "setting up deep link support" halfway down this page for pseudocode and a diagram. I am storing / retrieving a destination URL to go to when a user has authenticated with the OpenAthens Keystone WAYFless identity provider.

But it's kind of irrelevant - I would like to be able to store an retrieve *anything* in a cookie between the two requests, and am not sure what I've got wrong.
 https://docs.openathens.net/display/public/OAAccess/WAYFless+access+and+deep+linking+in+OpenAthens+Keystone

Comment: It's similar to how it is done in this example in IdentityServer4: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/master/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs (lines 50-90)

Although without the ChallengeResult in the first step.

Comment: It's asking you to simply store a return URL as far as I can tell. It doesn't require you to send this value to the external identifier. So it should be simple enough. You could use `Response.Cookies.Append("CookieName", "CookieValue", CookieOptions)` then in the next method you can read it from `Request.Cookies["CookieName"]`

Comment: Does this work for you?

Comment: Yeah, that’s a simple way of doing it. As a matter of principle, I’d like to know is the SignIn / Authenticate approach fundamentally incorrect. I really thought that was a way to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212443/discussion-between-dennis1679-and-user888734).